# Handling Multiple Social Login/Registration System

Tags: php, authentication, oauth

First let me clarify what am not asking. Am not asking how to do the Registration/Login itself. I can use OAuth with Twitter and FB for example, to register single user.

Now what am asking:
I have user table and socials table which holds user registration. When user tries to register with his social network, we also present a form for his "user" table information (Like birth-date) and then log him immediately. So far so good! Now Suppose *user logs out* and somehow this time *logs in with Twitter*. How should I connect the "user" table data since I have no idea its the same user already have registered?

I could use email, but some people have different email for Facebook and Twitter Account. In that case I will have duplicate profiles in "user" table. I know I can tell user to login and associate his social account with his twitter or create new profile. But am trying to check if there is anything I can do to associate user Twitter profile with same data in "user" table that user filled in when he used facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save all login data in the same `user` table. Force the user to actually connect the accounts they want to log in with. Then save the e-mail you get from each service and save it to the corresponding service column in DB.

E-mail is the only unique common thing about these accounts. I think this is the only way to do it.

Comment: I use separate table to only cater for future Social logins. I have no problem associating accounts with user logged in. Problem I try to solve is do so with user logged out (if its possible)

Comment: I think it's not possible because there is no unique identifier between many accounts if the e-mail is not the same. Only way to do this in my opinion is to force the user connect the accounts while logged in. Or then just take the risk for the user to have several e-mails and then it just creates a new account if the e-mail doesn't match.

Comment: I see. my fears that it might be impossible seems to be true!